# Pass a reference to the array name to the method through a loop

Tags: c#

I am writing through a translator. I want to pass a reference to the array name through a loop, below is the code.

```
byte[] mesSend_1 = { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x34, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x37, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30};

byte[] mesSend_2 = { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x38, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30 };

byte[] mesSend_3 = { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x30, 0x36, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x31, 0x30, 0x5f};

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{               
    ReadoutLis200.ExchangeFirstPhase(ref messageTxByteArgOne, 3000, 60, ref portDataFull, ref CheckBCCBool, coutPhase) break;
}
```

I plan to pass all the names, `mesSend_1`, `mesSend_2`, etc., to the method through the loop, but I don't understand how to do it.

I tried substituting an array of strings, but it gives an error because I use a reference to the array and not the array itself, I tried substituting the `i` value, but it didn't work out.

Comment: What array are you talking about? What is `messageTxByteArgOne` ? Put all arrays in another array or list and refer to each item. Why `ref` though? Are you trying to avoid copying the bytes?

Comment: You could use a `Memory<byte>` or `Span<byte>` if you want to modify the arrays

Comment: What array are you talking about? What is messageTxByteArgOne ? Put all arrays in another array or list and refer to each item. Why ref though? Are you trying to avoid copying the bytes? – 
Panagiotis Kanavos


The name messageTxByteArgOne is my mistake, there must be mesSend_2 I copied incorrectly, when I changed the code I forgot to return ctr+z and inserted a little incorrect, but the essence is still the same. Regarding the link, I need to pass exactly my array to the loop so that I can count BC and put it to the end of the array

Comment: You can't just append stuff to an array. You can *overwrite* the last byte, or you'll have to allocate a new array with one extra byte. You need a `List<byte>` if you intend to append data. Underneath it still stores the data in an array, but takes care of expanding it as needed

Comment: You could iterate over all arrays with `foreach(var messageTxByteArgOne in new[]{mesSend_1 ,mesSend_2,...})` but you still can't change the size of the arrays. You can only modify their contents

Comment: This sounds like a poster example for a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is it you are *actually* intending to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should name variables with numbers, but instead use an array.

Try this:

```
var mesSends = new []
{
    new byte[] { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x34, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x37, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30 },
    new byte[] { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x38, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x30 },
    new byte[] { 0x01, 0x52, 0x31, 0x02, 0x30, 0x36, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x31, 0x30, 0x5f },
};

for (int i = 0; i < mesSends.Length; i++)
{
    ReadoutLis200.ExchangeFirstPhase(ref mesSends[i]);
}
```